# How to use a user's submitted code, and get its errors to have relevant info?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

So I'm creating a mod for the singleplayer **browser** game Cookie Clicker. In my mod I allow the user to insert in their own code to do their own special things to interact with my mod's main function.

However, when the user codes on my custom editor, I want to "test" their code before they save to make sure no errors happen, and if they do, display a error message with what they did and where they did it. Getting the error is easy with a try/catch. But I noticed the error message is:

```
SynaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.save.onclick (chrome-extension://dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/userscript.html?name=Building%2520Sorter.user.js&id=18320655-b018-42e2-8fa5-7fb0cc8d2d70:578:24)
```

Which isn't helpful for me at all. The most I could salvage from this is the first line. However, that doesn't tell the user at all **where** the error is located in their code.

the `578:24` that points to the supposed error is:

```js
try{
    //code.value is a STRING of the user's code
    let func = new Function(code.value);//<-- error points here in my source code.
    func.call(null, [[0, 1, 2], Game]);
    save.classList.remove('ModBuildingSorter_unsaved');
}
catch(e){
    console.dir(e);
}
```

What I would *like* to happen is when the user sumbits:

```js
return function(array){
    return array.sort(function(building1,building2){
        return building1.price - building2.price;
    };// missing array.sort closing parenthesis
}
```

get's ran, I can get a `syntax error` telling me it's on `line 4`

Is there a way I can do this? Make the user's code act kinda like it's own file and try running it so I can find out which row & column the error is located?

Answer (score 0):

You could, in theory, run the function from an `eval()`

i.e.:

```
try {
    let a = "function test(o){console.lo(o)}test('hello');" // Minified function
    eval(a)
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

Here is the unminified function for example purposes:

```
function test(o)
{
console.lo(o) // <-- Error
}

test('hello');
```

and this returns the error correctly, which is

```
TypeError: console.lo is not a function
    at test (eval at <anonymous> (D:\StackOverflowSandbox\index.js:3:5), <anonymous>:1:26)
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: This isn't reliable. For example when running this in the eval: `"function(o){console.log(o);}"`, it returns *just*: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`  It appears SyntaxErrors when using eval, don't return line location, just the error. I've found ReferenceErrors & TypeErrors do, but not Syntax.